# Extract and add the particular typings from a class for properties and methods to a interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, conditional-types

Hello Typescript Professionals. I don't want a solution but a hint and if this is possible in Typescript. I am still relatively fresh with the Conditional Types. Is it possible to extract the typings from a class for properties and methods to a interface?

```
interface ExtractTypings<Class, MembersOrMethods> {
  // ?????
}

class Bar {
  a: boolean;
  b: number;
  c() {
    return 'some string';
  }
  d() {}
  e() {
    return new Observable<number>();
  }
}

class Foo implements ExtractTypings<Bar, ['a, c, e']> {

}
```

Version of Typescript: 3.4.5

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a conditional type for this, the builtin mapped type `Pick` should do the trick :

```
class Bar {
  a: boolean;
  b: number;
  c() {
    return 'some string';
  }
  d() {}
  e() {
    return new Observable<number>();
  }
}

class Foo implements Pick<Bar, 'a' |  'c' |  'e'> {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I undestand your intent correctly, you could do something like this:

```
type ExtractTypings<Class, MembersOrMethods extends (keyof Class)[]> =
Pick<Class, MembersOrMethods[number]>;

class Bar {
  a: boolean;
  b: number;
  c() {
    return 'some string';
  }
  d() {}
  e() {
    return new Observable<number>();
  }
}

class Foo implements ExtractTypings<Bar, ['a', 'c', 'e']> {

}
```

Note that if you don't need the members to be declared as an array Titian Dragomir's solution is preferable.

Comment: I didn't know it would work with Pick so I wanted to show my wish usage.

Comment: Could you explain what this does: MembersOrMethods[number] ! What's number doing in this place?

Comment: It creates a union of the types of all elements of `MembersOrMethods`, so it's basically the same as `'a' | 'c' | 'e'`. It's because array element keys are always of type `number`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I have found this two awesome typing libs which increases the number of typescript`s built-in types (Pick, Exclude, Extract, Merge, etc., ...) to for more great useful types (e.g. Head, Tail, Last, etc., ...):

- https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types
- https://github.com/pirix-gh/ts-toolbelt

Also to mention this good articles that helped me to understand on how to build my own complex types:

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/typescript-curry-ramda-types-f747e99744ab/ (*owner of ts-toolbelt*)
- https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/

**Note:** What I also found out is that the heart of these complex types to build is actually only `extends`, `type` and `infer`!